# How to rewrite the regex `^(?!master).+@` without the negative lookahead?

Tags: regex, gitlab-ci

How to rewrite the regex `^(?!master).+@` without the negative lookahead?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: Why do you not want the negative lookahead?

Comment: @Sweeper not longer supported in the engine I am forced to use...

Comment: @AleksW anything that does not start with `master` followed by anything with an `@`

Comment: @ndnenkov sure, actually it's the kind of regex that can be accepted in the gitlab-ci.yml, it used to be the case that regex worked, but since the last update, everything is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:[^m]|m[^a]|ma[^s]|mas[^t]|mast[^e]|maste[^r]).*@
```

**Update** - in case you need one for both `master` and `main`:

```
^(?:[^m]|m[^a]|ma[^si]|mai[^n]|mas[^t]|mast[^e]|maste[^r]).*@
```

Comment: not supposed to have a `+` instead of `*` at the end: `^(?:[^m]|m[^a]|ma[^s]|mas[^t]|mast[^e]|maste[^r]).+@`?

Comment: @EhouarnPerret the `+` means "one or more characters", while `*` means "zero or more characters". Given that we already matched at least one character in the brackets (for example `[^m]` is exactly one character), we may or may not need another one. Hence why it's `*` and not `+`.

Comment: makes sense, you're awesome!

Comment: Happy to help <3

Comment: Work very well ! Even if that s*cks to be forced to use a such syntax...

Comment: However it doesn't work if you want to avoid `master` AND `main` :/

Comment: @TBG then you can do a big `|` and repeat do the same for `main`.

Comment: @ndnenkov I tried but it didn't work, at least when I tested it on regex101 ... Do you have a working example ?

Comment: @TBG well what didn't work exactly? Could you post a regex so that I could suggest a fix for it.

Comment: @ndnenkov I started from your answer https://regex101.com/r/GYX742/1 and I modified it to also avoid main, here is one of my tries : https://regex101.com/r/dW7CzD/1

Comment: @TBG here's an [updated working version](https://regex101.com/r/j03d9p/1).

Comment: @ndnenkov Awesome, thanks a lot ! However I supposed there is no way of avoiding `mastere` or `mainu` being excluded ? And how would you generate that for a list of words ? I had a bash script but in fact it only works for one word, as I built it on your first answer... I think I will end up doing a loop on a "simple" regex, instead of finding a regex that covers all cases/words

Comment: @TBG the original question required stuff starting with `master` to be excluded, not `master` alone. So `mastere` and `mainu` change the scope of the question. Ask a separate one. And yes, if you have control over it (like it's a bash script) I wouldn't build a mega-regex and match against a list of words. Instead I would check one by one without regexes. xd

Answer (score 2):

You may phrase this problem as being logically equivalent to saying match any string which does *not* begin with `master`, and which contains an at symbol:

```
input = "some random text @";

if (input !~ /^master/ && input =~ /.*@.*/)   # or /.*@$/ if it must end in an @
    puts "MATCH"
end
```